# Rellene las opciones SELECT con Ajax. y Materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de incrustar datos que me muestran en JSON desde una REST API mediante AJAX Y JQUERY, desde el siguiente select que por ende estoy usando Materialize.css

```html
<div class="input-field col s12 m4">
    <select>

    </select>
    <label>Seleccionar Región</label>
</div>
```

Lo que muestra el varlo de "res"en la parte de "success" es la matriz de objetos que me retorna la url con el nombre de regiones:

```js
{
  regiones: [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e3733d6e3091231ac95f73d"),
        "nombre" : "Región 1 ",
        "__v" : 0
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e3733e4e3091231ac95f73e"),
            "nombre" : "Región Centro 2",
            "__v" : 0
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e3733f6e3091231ac95f73f"),
            "nombre" : "Región 3",
            "__v" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

hasta aqui creo que estoy haciendo en lo correcto porque muestro los datos en un console.log() y normal puedo apreciar esa matriz e incluso cuando lo inserto a una tabla. El detalle es que Estoy haciendo el siguiente método con AJAX:

```js
function cargarRegiones(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/api/region/mostrarRegiones',
            success: function(res){
                let select = $('select')
                select.html('')
                let obj = res

                obj.regiones.forEach((elemento, indice) => {
                    select.append(`
                        <option value="${indice}">${elemento.nombre}</option>
                    `)
                });

            },
            error: function(res){
                let error = res.responseJSON.mensaje
                console.log(error)
            }
        })
    }
```

Pero practicamente solo me muestra el primer objeto mas no los demas objetos en la etiqueta "" Por favor si alguien me pueda explicar que estoy haciendo mal. o quizá esté aplicando mal en la parte del foreach O derepente es porque estoy usando Materialize.css el inconveniente.

Comment: ¿Podrías imprimir un ejemplo de la respuesta contenida en res?, sería de utilidad para saber si es un problema de iteración o de logica como tal, saludos!

Comment: @Nalius la respuesta contenida en res es el arreglo con el nombre **regiones**  que muestro arriba, pero solo al tratar de crear las opciones en el select me muestra el primero y no me salen los demas, hasta pienso que es un defecto de materialize.css o algo asi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás insertando datos dinámicamente y estás inicializando el plugin antes de tener los datos. Intenta insertando esta línea después de agregar los datos al select `$('select').formSelect();` [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

probaste luego de añadir las etiquetas option ejecutar un trigger change? te paso el código:

```
function cargarRegiones(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/region/mostrarRegiones',
        success: function(res){
            let select = $('select')
            select.html('')
            let obj = res

            obj.regiones.forEach((elemento, indice) => {
                select.append(`
                    <option value="${indice}">${elemento.nombre}</option>
                `)

            });
            $('select').trigger('change');
        },
        error: function(res){
            let error = res.responseJSON.mensaje
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: no me funciona, nisiquiera me muestra el efecto del select que usa materialize cuando hago click al seleccionar solo me muestra el primer elemento como si fuera un input o como si mostraria un elemento en un div

Comment: No lo tenes online como para verlo? tiene que ser una pavada. hace poco estuve con lo mismo